# Python returns ImportError when running a script from another module in windows terminal

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I have a project in the following (simplified) structure.

```
MyProject
|__Module1
    __init__.py
    -script11
|__Module2
    __init__.py
    -script22
__init__.py
```

script11's contents:

```
var11 = "hello"
```

script22's contents:

```
from MyProject.Module1.script11 import var11
print var11
```

When I run script22 from inside PyCharm it runs fine.
When I run it from Windows/PyCharm terminal it prints an ImportError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Project\Python27\Projects\folder1\MyProject\Module2\script22.py", line 3, in <module>
    from MyProject.module1.script11 import hello
ImportError: No module named MyProject.module1.script11
```

If I create a script11.py file in the same module/folder as script22.py , the script runs OK.

I have these entries in my ENV.VARIABLES:

```
F:\Schoox\Python27\python.exe;
F:\Schoox\Python27;
F:\Schoox\Python27\Lib;
F:\Schoox\Python27\Scripts;
F:\Schoox\Python27\lib\site-packages;
F:\Schoox\Python27\Projects\folder1\; (I have tried also with ...folder1\MyProject)
```

What is going wrong???
I am essentially not able to use all the modules of my project freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because, Your module is not in the pythonpath and hence the script is unable to find the required modules , PyCharms adds the current project to PythonPATH and hence when running from PyCharms, the modules are resolved and you see no issues.

To overcome these issues, you can do one of the following.

1. Add "F:\Schoox\Python27\Projects\folder1\" to PATH environment variable [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)
2. move the project to "c:\python<>\lib\site-packages" (not recommended)
3. Append the path "F:\Schoox\Python27\Projects\folder1\" to sys.path dynamically before you import your module

so your script22.py becomes

```
import sys
sys.path.append(F:\Schoox\Python27\Projects\folder1\) 
from MyProject.Module1.script11 import var11
print var11
```

check https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching for how python handles import and the order of look-up.

Comment: Thanks Sanju, appending the project path dynamically to sys.path worked . This is definitely a solution that works....but by adding the project path to the 'Path' system variable for a more permanent solution, it does not work.  (I commented out the sys.path.append(...) and restarted the terminal.) Is there a way to permanently set the project's path so windows terminal finds it by default? Should I make a new system/environmental variable with the project's path as value?

Comment: Did you try the most voted answer the link I quoted above for setting the path variable (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/2772269) ? , It should work generally . Restarting the terminal should do the trick , if not try the good old windows method to fix things , "RESTART" !!!

Comment: Amazing and amazingly profound. My work with Linux made me forget Windows's quirks.... I had set many times the ENV VAR as PythonPath or PYTHONPATH and wasnt working cause I didnt RESTART Windows. Problem solved